# Where change the size of the window in Bitcoin code?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development, source-code

I already try changeing the height and width parameters of the forms in src/qt/forms but nothing changes, where else i need to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open one of the `.ui` files from [/src/qt/forms](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/gui/tree/master/src/qt/forms) in [Qt Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdesigner-manual.html)

[image: qt-designer-1]

2. Press CTRL+O or click on [Form] -> [Break Layout]
3. Resize the form and different objects accordingly

[image: resize-qt-designer]

4. Compile and run `bitcoin-qt`

[image: resized-ui-1]

[image: resized-ui-2]

I changed width and height in `minimumSize` property and same in `geometry`. Also made few changes in [`rpcconsole.cpp`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/qt/rpcconsole.cpp) because I removed some objects, its not related to resizing the forms.